# How to check if channel name contains a certain word in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and I want to send a message to the general chat channel. I found a way to do this by doing `if(channel.name == 'general'):` but the problem with this is if the general chat is instead `general-chat` or `∙ General` it wont send. So I need it to be something like `if(channel.name.contains  == 'general'):` but I have no clue how I would go about it.

Thankyou.

Comment: Send by ID! That'll sort your problems. In discord set yourself in developer mode and right click channels for their IDs. Best way in my opinion. You should never match via name.

Comment: `if(lower(channel.name).startswith('general')`

Comment: @blanknamefornow ye that would work if it was just my server. But it a broadcast command where it will send a certain message in every server that the bot is in. Sorry for not making that clear

Comment: Yup that's fine, you can then do a search through all guilds your bot is apart of and then send message to any channel it has permissions to write in. Doesn't require a name at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python strings have the `__contains__` dunder method which is represented by the `in` keyword:

```py
>>> name = "general-chat"
>>> "general" in name
True
>>> name.__contains__("general")
True
```

You can also use the `string.lower()` method to be case insensitive (Though uppercase/capitalized channel names can only be in voice-channels so this step is pointless)

```py
>>> name = "General"
>>> "general" in name.lower()
True
```

You can use the same principle in your command:

```py
if "general" in channel.name.lower():
   ...
```